# GNU Scientific Library in an iOS app

Tags: ios, gsl

How can I install the GNU Scientific Library for use on iOS?
i have xcode 5.0 and ios 7.0

my error is:

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib/libgsl.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib/libgsl.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib/libgslcblas.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib/libgslcblas.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_gsl_sf_erfc_e", referenced from:
      NUMerfcc(double) in support.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I previously installed version of gsl 1-16 using the standard procedure through "configure", "make" and "make install"

thanks

Comment: in that post I can not find a solution because it is relative to two years ago. 
I wish someone could explain to me in detail through a sequence of instructions how to risolvare the problem

Comment: If you've tried to add the library and have run into a specific problem, edit your question to ask about that. Was there an error message?

Comment: ok I change the question